# Retrieve image from mongodb + gridfs to Ember js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ember.js, sails.js

I have a function in Ember JS that uploads an image to Sails JS which uses the "gridfs" adapter to store the image in a Mongo db, so far so good.

I can see the chunks and files records updating and everything is working smoothly.

The problem is in retrieving the image itself, I don't know why but it seems the Ember couldn't find the image that was just uploaded, I tried to use the read method described in the "gridfs" adapter but got nothing still.

Here is my Ember Template

```
<div class="image">
    {{#each model.files as |image|}}
        <img src="http:localhost:1337/{{file.path}}" class="img-thumbnail">
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

My Upload method in Ember's controller is :

```
upload(file) {
    file.upload('http://localhost:1337/uploads/file').then(response => {
        this.get('model.files).pushObject({ path : response.body.file })
})
```

My Upload Controller in Sails JS is :

```
module.exports = {
    file : function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);
        req.file('file').upload({
            adapter : require('skipper-gridfs'),
            uri : 'mongodb://192.168.99.100:32769/admin.uploads',
        }, function (err, files) {
            if (err) return res.negotiate('this is my error ' + err);
            skipperAdapter.read(files, function(error, file) {
                if (err) return res.negotiate('Reading Error' + err);
                console.log(files, file);
                res.json({ file : files[0] })
            })
        })
    }
};
```

Also tried

```
module.exports = {
    file : function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);
        req.file('file').upload({
            adapter : require('skipper-gridfs'),
            uri : 'mongodb://192.168.99.100:32769/admin.uploads',
        }, function (err, files) {
            if (err) return res.negotiate('this is my error ' + err);
            res.json( { file : files[0].fd.split('/assets') } )[0]
        });
    }
};
```

I get an error "GET http://localhost:1338/237e0d9e-7554-41e0-b2ac-666cdc5c2efa.jpg 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: 2 possibilities, In your ember template you are missing // after http in source. In your get request you are calling port 1338. Or are these just typos?

Comment: sorry, but both of them are just typo's in the question i'll edit them, any other solution you think of ? help appreciated @Glen

Answer (score 0):

I would start with this:

> i get an error "GET
>   http://localhost:1338/237e0d9e-7554-41e0-b2ac-666cdc5c2efa.jpg 404
>   (Not Found)"

So first you should check who is serving that endpoint that returns 404. Do you have a route and a controller that responds to urls that match: `/:file_name`?

What else you can do is to try to serve a hardcoded file (image) dynamically (via controller action) through that endpoint to be sure that everything else works ok. And then you can see what else is wrong with your integration with gridfs. My guess is that you cannot use filepath directly as you tried but need to use it to query gridfs for a file and then stream/return the response from gridfs to a client (via a controller action). What I mean is doing something similar to the code below (taken from https://ciphertrick.com/2017/02/28/file-upload-with-nodejs-and-gridfs-mongodb/):

```
app.get('/file/:filename', function(req, res){
    // replace gfs with whatever you make a connection to gfs with e.g. the adapter you're mentioning
    gfs.collection('ctFiles'); //set collection name to lookup into

    /** First check if file exists */
    gfs.files.find({filename: req.params.filename}).toArray(function(err, files){
        if(!files || files.length === 0){
            return res.status(404).json({
                responseCode: 1,
                responseMessage: "error"
            });
        }
        /** create read stream */
        var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
            filename: files[0].filename,
            root: "ctFiles"
        });
        /** set the proper content type */
        res.set('Content-Type', files[0].contentType)
        /** return response */
        return readstream.pipe(res);
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried to access the image uploaded by going to 'localhost:1337/uploads/[fileName]' i get nothing, and when i visit 'http:localhost:1337/uploads' i get an empty array, i don't get it how can i access the image that is stored in upload.file or upload.chunks or whatever the collection my image was stored in ? please help me with this issue and i'll be grateful.